# Is additional venting needed for my basement bathroom finish?

Tags: drain

My house was built in 2015 and was pre plumbed for a basement bathroom. I called the city and all they can tell me is that a pre pour plumbing inspection was completed. There is the shower, toilet and sink drains along with a vent for the sink coming from above (highlighted all for clarity). The ejector pit is right adjacent to the bathroom and vented as well.

My question is whether any additional venting would be needed. I'm assuming that the shower connects to the toilet and sink drains before heading to the ejector pit which is vented. I am assuming that the shower has some sort of wet vent that would not require a trap to be installed before connecting to the shower pan drain?

Also, as far as a plumbing rough in inspection is concerned, I assume the sink faucet and toilet do not have to be connected until the final plumbing inspection is performed. Is this correct?

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The vent stub isn't just for the sink. It's likely intended for all three fixtures. The key question is probably the trap arm lengths. Each fixture/trap type has a maximum.

Comment: Purdue grad, eh? ;) Sinks, faucets & toilets are _finish_ plumbing and should not be installed prior to a plumbing _rough-in_ inspection.

Comment: The box for the shower drain is left so you can adjust position if needed. If there's not already a trap there you'll need to add one. It'll be a cemented assembly in 2". What's there now?

Comment: @isherwood There is currently a 2" stub in the middle of the shower drain box out...It sits about 6" down from top of slab elevation.

Comment: Yep, and is there a trap on it?

Comment: @isherwood Nope, just the stub. Ill install a trap there just to be safe. Thanks

Comment: Not to "be safe", but because it's standard and required. You don't want sewer stink filling your bathroom. :)

Comment: Did you actually dig down a ways to be sure? Traps can be quite low to accommodate the slope of other plumbing. You can't tell by looking down the pipe, as a trap U and an elbow look the same.